# Vector2 2D arrays in XNA

Tags: c#, xna

I am trying to create 2D vector2 arrays in XNA,C#.

I used the following statement:

```
Vector2[][] SpritePosition=new Vector2[4][];
```

Then I used the following for loop to initialize them:

```
for(i=0;i<4;i++)  
{  
    for(j=0;j<4;j++)  
    {  
    }  
}
```

However, when I used the for loop, as stated above, it gave me an error, actually two:

1. Int is a field and used as a type.
2. 'for' is an invalid token in class, struct or interface member declaration.

Can anyone tell why am I facing such a problem?

EDIT: This is the code:

```
public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    int i=new int();
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    Texture2D texture;
    //Vector2[,] SpritePosition = new Vector2[4,4];
    Vector2[,] SpriteSpeed = new Vector2[4,4];
    for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Can You give us the exact errors (Full code and line #'s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you need to read up on some [C# Tutorials](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial.aspx/)

You are going to need a function for that as so,

```
void LoadArray()
{
for(int i=0;i<4;i++)  
{  
    for(int j=0;j<4;j++)  
    {  
SpritePosition[i,j] = new Vector2(i,j)
    }  
}
```

You can call it from your initialize method, using `LoadArray()`

}

Also, You dont need int `i = new Int()` for basic stuff like strings, ints, etc you dont need the new Whatever() part

Just do

`for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
    }`

Answer (score 0):

for #2, it means your for loop isn't inside of a function... so there's probably an extra } somewhere higher up in your code that you didn't mean to put there.  there's a good chance that this is also the problem with #1 but you haven't really given us enough context (more code or where exactly the compiler says the error is) to say for sure

Comment: And I did check, there is no extra } so that isn't a problem

Comment: it looks like you could benefit from an "intro to c#" book.  `int i=new int();` should just be `int i = 0;`  and you can't just stick executable code inside a class... you put functions inside of classes and the executable code goes inside those functions

Comment: Okay, Actually I have been programming only in C++ and C and VB.NET so OOP is still a bit new to me